# How to intercept scroll event in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, events, scroll, dom-events

How to prevent scroll event?

I was trying to add `event.preventDefault()` into the HostListener but it's not working. `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` are not working too.

I need to implement some logic instead of scrolling.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```

Comment: try using `'wheel'` instead of `'window:scroll'`

Comment: @RadekF Thank you! It's working. Add your answer

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear that you want to intercept the scrolling with the mouse wheel (not using the scroll bar).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Actually I want to intercept scroll event. It doesn't matter wheel or scroll bar. If you know how to prevent both triggers let me know please.

Comment: You can use the trick given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770059/1009922): reset the scroll position in the event handler. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bp8lq9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: And here is [another stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plyafa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) showing how to allow/disallow scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `'wheel'` instead of `'window:scroll'`